# What is the sum of the first n terms of the series: 1+1-1+1+1-1+........

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I have actually found an answer to this . It looks like this:$$S_n = \frac{n- n (\bmod3)}{3} + n(\bmod3)$$

But if there is any problem in my answer or if there is a different answer ,  I would like to know.

Comment: Note that $1+1-1=1$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to write it is
$$S_n = \begin{cases} 
k & \text{if}~ n = 3k+0 \\
k+1 & \text{if}~ n = 3k+1 \\
k+2 & \text{if}~ n = 3k+2 \\
\end{cases}$$
or
$$S_n = \left\lfloor \frac n 3 \right\rfloor + \left(n \bmod 3\right)$$
or since $\left\lfloor\frac ab \right\rfloor \cdot b + (a \bmod b) = a$

$$S_n = \frac{n - (n \bmod 3)}3 + (n \bmod 3) = \frac 23 (n\bmod 3) + \frac13 n$$